# Jhipster webpack compilation error when checking an array value

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, webpack, jhipster

I am using Jhipster with Angular. I have a method that is trying to check to see if the user in as admin.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import { IPost } from 'app/shared/model/post.model';
import { AccountService } from 'app/core/auth/account.service';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import { Account } from 'app/core/user/account.model';

@Component({
  selector: 'jhi-post-detail',
  templateUrl: './post-detail.component.html'
})
export class PostDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  post: IPost | null = null;
  authSubscription!: Subscription;
  account: Account | null = null;

  constructor(protected activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute, private accountService: AccountService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activatedRoute.data.subscribe(({ post }) => (this.post = post));
    this.authSubscription = this.accountService.getAuthenticationState().subscribe(account => (this.account = account));
  }

  previousState(): void {
    window.history.back();
  }

  private isAdmin(): boolean | undefined {
    return this.account?.authorities.includes('ROLE_ADMIN');
  }
}
```

When the code is compiled I get an error

```
ERROR in ./src/main/webapp/app/entities/post/post-detail.component.ts 21:30
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (21:30)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/angular2-template-loader/index.js
 * ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js
 * ./node_modules/thread-loader/dist/cjs.js
 * ./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js
 * ./node_modules/eslint-loader/dist/cjs.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
|     }
|     isAdmin() {
>         return this.account ? .authorities.includes('ROLE_ADMIN') : ;
|     }
| };
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

As a workaround, if I just hard-code the return value to 'true' in the isAdmin() method it works and compiles. How come just checking to see if the array contains something causes the webpack to freak out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Optional chaining](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining) was introduced in Typescript 3.7, current JHipster 6.7.1 uses Typescript 3.4.5 so it's not very surprising that your expression is not understood and translated as ternary operator.

Try upgrading typescript version in package.json and npm install to see if it solves it.

Comment: Ah I didn't know that. Updating typescript helped and it ran locally, but when I try to deploy it says that angular cli needs upgrading too. I wish there was a way to fix that without having to update typescript

Comment: Just be patient ;) this feature was introduced only recently,  and you can easily write your code differently.

Comment: Most definitely  Just lately getting back into the Angular scene